# p:commandButton not takes the parameter that specify in the onsuccess function

Tags: java, jquery, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

i have a problem, in the onsuccess of the commandButton i have a javascript function that obtains a string parameter but when i see the generated DOM any paramter is passed, so my function returns a exception for undefined reference:

My xhtml:

```
<h:head>

    <h:outputScript library="js" name="jsfcrud.js" target="body" />
    <h:outputScript name="jquery/jquery.js" library="primefaces" target="head" />
    <h:outputScript name="jquery/jquery-plugins.js" library="primefaces" target="head" />

    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="jsfcrud.css"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div id="cabezote" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 logo">
                <img src="http://aprende.colombiaaprende.edu.co/sites/all/themes/aprende/images/h_logo_2.png" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 titulo">
                <h1>Foro de Educación Nacional 2016</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <b:container>
        <b:row>
            <h:form id="formulario-registro">
                <p:wizard  flowListener="#{RegistroBean.onFlowProcess}" backLabel="Anterior" nextLabel="Siguiente" id="wizard-flow">
                    <p:tab title="Registro" id="personal-tab">
                        <p:panel header="Datos personales:" id="personal-panel">
                            <p:messages id="messages-personal"/>

                            <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="grid-personal" columnClasses="label, value">
                                <h:outputText styleClass="label-form requ" value="Nombres:" />
                                <p:inputText required="true" label="Nombres" value="#{RegistroBean.user.nombres}"/>
                                <h:outputText styleClass="label-form requ" value="Apellidos:" />
                                <p:inputText required="true" label="Apellidos" value="#{RegistroBean.user.apellidos}"/>
                                <h:outputText styleClass="label-form requ" value="Tipo de documento:" />
                                <p:selectOneMenu id="console" value="#{RegistroBean.user.tipoDocumento}">
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="CC" itemValue="CC" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="CE" itemValue="CE" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="PASAPORTE" itemValue="PS" />
                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                                <h:outputText styleClass="label-form requ" value="Numero de documento:" />
                                <p:inputText required="true" label="Numero de documento" value="#{RegistroBean.user.numeroDocumento}"/>
                                <h:outputText styleClass="label-form requ" value="Correo:" />
                                <p:inputText required="true" size="80" value="#{RegistroBean.user.correo}" style="width: 40%"
                                             requiredMessage="Valor requerido" label="Correo"
                                             validatorMessage="Formato de email invalido">
                                    <f:validateRegex pattern="[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]" />
                                </p:inputText>

                                <h:outputText styleClass="label-form requ" value="Telefono:" />
                                <p:inputText value="#{RegistroBean.user.telefono}"/>
                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </p:panel>

                    </p:tab>
                    <p:tab id="institucion" title="Institución">
                        <p:panel header="Datos de institución" id="institucion-panel">
                            <p:messages id="institucion-messages"/>
                            <h:panelGrid id="institucion-grid" columns="2" columnClasses="label, value">
                                <h:outputText styleClass="label-form requ" value="Nombres de la institucion:" />
                                <p:inputText required="true" label="Nombre institucion" value="#{RegistroBean.institucion.nombre}"/>
                                <h:outputText styleClass="label-form requ" value="Direccion: " />
                                <p:inputText required="false" label="Direccion institucion" value="#{RegistroBean.institucion.direccion}"/>
                                <h:outputText styleClass="label-form requ" value="Ciudad: " />
                                <p:inputText required="false" label="Direccion institucion" value="#{RegistroBean.institucion.ciudad}"/>
                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </p:panel>
                    </p:tab>
                    <c:forEach items="#{RegistroBean.daysWithEvent}" var="day">
                        <p:tab title="Programacion: #{day}">
                            <p:panel header="Mañana" toggleable="true" collapsed="false" styleClass="panel-fecha" rendered="#{RegistroBean.hasAm(RegistroBean.findByDate(day))}">
                                <p:dataGrid var="ejecucion" value="#{RegistroBean.findByDate(day)}" emptyMessage="No hay talleres en la mañana" columns="2" layout="grid"  
                                            rows="12" paginator="false" styleClass="grid-data-fecha">                                       
                                    <p:panel id="panel-fecha" styleClass="#{RegistroBean.comprobeIsAm(ejecucion.horaInicio) ? 'amEvent':'pmEvent'}" rendered="#{RegistroBean.comprobeIsAm(ejecucion.horaInicio)}" style="text-align:center" >
                                        <p:panel id="contenedor-ejecucion">
                                            <h:panelGrid  columns="2" style="width:100%" id="ejecucion-taller-grid">  
                                                <h:outputText style=" font-weight: bold" value="Hora inicio: " styleClass="table-important"/>
                                                <h:outputText style=" font-weight: bold" value="#{ejecucion.horaInicio}" />

                                                <h:outputText value="Taller: " styleClass="table-important"/>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{ejecucion.tallerIdTaller.nombre}" />

                                                <h:outputText value="Ponente: " styleClass="table-important"/>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{ejecucion.tallerIdTaller.ponente.nombres} #{ejecucion.tallerIdTaller.ponente.apellidos}" />

                                                <h:outputText value="Lugar " styleClass="table-important"/>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{ejecucion.locacionEspecificaIdlocacionEspecifica.sitioIdSitio.nombre} - #{ejecucion.locacionEspecificaIdlocacionEspecifica.nombre}" />

                                                <h:outputText value="Cupo: " styleClass="table-important"/>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{ejecucion.cupo}" />                                           
                                            </h:panelGrid>
                                        </p:panel>     
                                        <p:commandButton widgetVar="ejecucion#{ejecucion.idEjecucionTaller}" onsuccess="inactivarJornada('ejecucion#{ejecucion.idEjecucionTaller}')" ajax="true" actionListener="#{RegistroBean.asistir(ejecucion)}" update="@(.asistirButton)" styleClass="asistirButton" value="#{RegistroBean.isInPlanner(ejecucion)?'Cancelar Asistencia':'Asistir'}"  disabled="#{ejecucion.cupo_disponible == 0}"/>
                                        <div id="reference" class=""></div>
                                    </p:panel>
                                </p:dataGrid>
                            </p:panel>
                            <p:panel header="Tarde" toggleable="true" collapsed="false" styleClass="panel-fecha"  rendered="#{RegistroBean.hasPm(RegistroBean.findByDate(day))}">
                                <p:dataGrid var="ejecucion" value="#{RegistroBean.findByDate(day)}" columns="2" emptyMessage="No hay talleres en la tarde" layout="grid"
                                            rows="12" paginator="false" styleClass="grid-data-fecha">                                       
                                    <p:panel id="panel-fecha" styleClass="#{RegistroBean.comprobeIsAm(ejecucion.horaInicio) ? 'amEvent':'pmEvent'}" rendered="#{!RegistroBean.comprobeIsAm(ejecucion.horaInicio)}" style="text-align:center" >
                                        <p:panel id="contenedor-ejecucion">
                                            <h:panelGrid  columns="2" style="width:100%" id="ejecucion-taller-grid">  
                                                <h:outputText style=" font-weight: bold" value="Hora inicio: " styleClass="table-important"/>
                                                <h:outputText style=" font-weight: bold" value="#{ejecucion.horaInicio}" />

                                                <h:outputText value="Taller: " styleClass="table-important"/>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{ejecucion.tallerIdTaller.nombre}" />

                                                <h:outputText value="Ponente: " styleClass="table-important"/>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{ejecucion.tallerIdTaller.ponente.nombres} #{ejecucion.tallerIdTaller.ponente.apellidos}" />

                                                <h:outputText value="Lugar " styleClass="table-important"/>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{ejecucion.locacionEspecificaIdlocacionEspecifica.sitioIdSitio.nombre} - #{ejecucion.locacionEspecificaIdlocacionEspecifica.nombre}" />

                                                <h:outputText value="Cupo: " styleClass="table-important"/>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{ejecucion.cupo}" />                                           
                                            </h:panelGrid>
                                        </p:panel>     
                                        <p:commandButton widgetVar="ejecucion#{ejecucion.idEjecucionTaller}" onsuccess="inactivarJornada()" ajax="true" actionListener="#{RegistroBean.asistir(ejecucion)}" update="@(.asistirButton)" styleClass="asistirButton" value="#{RegistroBean.isInPlanner(ejecucion)?'Cancelar Asistencia':'Asistir'}"  disabled="#{ejecucion.cupo_disponible == 0}"/>
                                    </p:panel>
                                </p:dataGrid>
                            </p:panel>
                        </p:tab>
                    </c:forEach>
                    <p:tab id="confirmacion" title="Confirmación">
                        <p:messages id="confirmacion-messages"/>
                        <p:dialog header="Info" widgetVar="successDialog" id="successDialog" minHeight="40"  closable="false">
                            <h:outputText id="info-modal" value="Registro exitoso! ya estas confirmado como asistente a los eventos que seleccionaste" />
                            <p:button value="Aceptar" outcome="registro.xhtml"></p:button>
                        </p:dialog> 
                        <p:panel header="CONFIRMACIÓN">
                            <h:outputText id="info-confirmacion" value=" 
                                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                                          Aliquam euismod faucibus nibh, vel fringilla ex euismod ac.
                                          Praesent maximus pellentesque enim. Maecenas quis mattis orci,
                                          quis tempor est. Morbi ut gravida felis. Vestibulum non nisi nec
                                          massa sagittis lobortis. Donec sagittis libero ut tellus dictum varius.
                                          Curabitur semper dictum tincidunt. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed turpis turpis,
                                          ullamcorper in lorem ut, euismod interdum dui. Sed et nulla laoreet, placerat
                                          tortor at, venenatis purus. Mauris quis velit bibendum, sollicitudin libero in,
                                          aliquam nisi. Suspendisse potenti.">
                            </h:outputText>
                            <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="mailing-confirmation">
                                <h:outputText id="mailing-confirmation-desc" value="Deseo recibir un correo con la confirmacion de mi horario"/>
                                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkbox-mailing" value="#{RegistroBean.mailConfirm}"/>
                            </h:panelGrid>
                            <p:commandButton id="submit-button" value="Enviar" process="@form" update="@form" action="#{RegistroBean.savePlanner()}"/>
                        </p:panel>
                    </p:tab>
                </p:wizard>
            </h:form>   
        </b:row>
    </b:container>

</h:body>
```

This is the correspondent html generated:

[image]

And my javascript function:

```
function inactivarJornada(widgetVar) {
var currentObject = PrimeFaces.widgets["ejecucion"+widgetVar].jq
var currentId = PrimeFaces.escapeClientId(currentObject.attr("id"));

var jornadaContainer = currentObject.parent().parent();
var currentJornada = jornadaContainer.hasClass("amEvent") ? "amEvent" : "pmEvent";
jornadaContainer.parent().find("." + currentJornada).each(function () {
    if (PrimeFaces.escapeClientId(jQuery(this).attr("id")) != currentId) {
        currentJornada.parent().css({"display": "none"});
    }
})
```

}

**NOTE: 
I can't make it work putting the function within a $(document).ready(function(){}), when the button calls there return "undefined function" and i have to find the element by the widget var because when i'm trying get $(this) inside the function returns the window object , if someone knows how please help me :( !**

Comment: There is another button in your source which has `onsuccess="inactivarJornada()"``

Comment: @Holger cant have two buttons with the same onsuccess listener ?

Comment: Sure, but the second one calls the method without parameter